# Use custom Substrate node name (Substrate FRAME pallet + Polkadot/Substrate frontend)

Tags: substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

**Scenario:** You want to **submit an extrinsic to your custom [Substrate](https://substrate.dev/) node** based on the [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) by using the [Polkadot/Substrate frontend](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/extrinsics?rpc=ws://127.0.0.1:9944). You have **renamed the Substrate node** either manually by carefully searching and replacing all occurences of substarte-node-template or by using [danforbes renaming script](https://github.com/danforbes/substrate-devhub-utils)

**Problem:** When you try to **submit an extrinsic** to your Substrate node using the Polkadot/Substrate frontend, you receive an **error message in the frontend**:

> 1002: Verification Error: Execution: Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: No such variant in enum MultiSignature: RuntimeApi, Execution: Could not convert parameter `tx` between node and runtime: No such variant in enum MultiSignature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:** as [JoshOrndorff](https://github.com/JoshOrndorff) stated in a [Github issue](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/78):

> [...] The problem now is because the UI needs to know the types your node
> uses. When you use the node template, the UI detects it, and uses the
> appropriate types for you. Sine you have renamed your template, the UI
> cannot tell that it is still basically the node template, so you need
> to add your own custom types. In the Apps UI, go the the developer
> settings, and enter:
>
> ```
> {
>    "Address": "AccountId",
>    "LookupSource": "AccountId"
> }
> ```

Comment: Related topic - how to add custom types (in the frontend): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64601832/use-custom-types-substrate-frame-pallet-polkadot-substrate-frontend

Answer (score 1):

Now that metadata can be read from on chain this should not be a problem any more.